# Qlikview selection to work on multiple fields

Tags: listbox, multiple-columns, qlikview

I have three different tables that contain a similar field ('Department') meaning the possible values in each of them are exactly the same. I have a sheet that shows different objects let's say charts, line graphs, straight table etc based on table 1, 2 or 3. Now because the tables are not directly connected, I can't just have a listbox that selects works on all of them for that column. I want to have a single selection like a listbox based on one of them but a selection is made is like show me all possible values where
Field A = Field B = Field C and on deselect i want to have the same behaviour
Probably I will have to use macros but I am not finding any good guidance.

Answer (score 0):

For this case you can use the set analysis `p()` function.

For example if your fields are named `Department` and `Department1`. Then you have have your listbox based on `Department` field and in the charts where is needed `Department1` selection you can write expression like this:

```
sum( {< Department1 = p( Department ) >} Value)
```

This will show `sum( Value )` where selected/possible values in `Department` are equal to `Department1`

As of the macros - they should be your really, really final solution and try to avoid them. They dont work on 100% when the document is published on the server and they are single threaded, which can lead to performance issues with your app.

Comment: I really don't want to change my expression in every place they are used. Maybe use actions on the selection of the fields.

Comment: You can use action to select fields from one field to another. Have a look at this -> http://blog.axc.net/using-buttons-to-select-field-values . Personally i prefer the set analysis. Using the action actually will make the selection in the field and when you press the "back" button you will need to go through this selection as well